# What does this test mean?

Tags: stata

```
dfuller Demand
```

Dickey-Fuller test for unit root                   Number of obs   =        50

```
              ---------- Interpolated Dickey-Fuller ---------
            Test         1% Critical       5% Critical     10% Critical
         Statistic         Value            Value           Value      
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
Z(t)           -14.272            -4.380            -3.600            -3.240
   -------------------------------------------------------------------


      MacKinnon approximate p-value for Z(t) = 0.0000
```

Comment: [Dickey-Fuller on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test). Also see [How to ask a good question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated)

Comment: Sure. Will elaborate in a better way